# What does the word "for" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider the following sentence

> The policeman whistled **for** the automobile to stop.

The word "for " has 24 explanations in [longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/for_1), which explanation can match it?

Comment: From the dictionary site you link to: "3 used to say what the purpose of an object, action etc is"

Comment: In order to make the automobile stop.

Comment: It is a subordinator (subordinating conjunction) introducing the non-finite clause "For the automobile to stop".

Answer (score 5):

> **4.  in order to have, do, get, or obtain something**

as in:

> **ask for** vb (preposition)
>   1. to try to obtain by requesting: he asked for help.
>
> Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition
>   2014 © HarperCollins

or

> "a cry for help" in British English
>
> a way of saying that you need help:
>   Most suicide attempts are really a cry for help.
>   http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-cry-for-help

or

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Michael Swan's [Practical English Usage (para 291)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-English-Usage-Michael-Swan/dp/0194420981),  the "…for…to" structure is called "Infinitive with its own subject", which is widely used in English when the subject of the infinitive is the object of the preposition *for*.

Answer (score 1):

We can describe the *goal* or  *intention* of a volitional action (command, demand, request, desire, wish, etc) using this pattern:

{subject} {verb phrase} for  {object of prep}  to {verb phrase}

> The king called for his fiddlers to play a tune.
>
> The audience chanted for the band to play an encore.
>
> The policeman whistled for the shoplifter to stop.
>
> The farmers prayed for the rain to continue.
>
> The barista shouted for Mike to fetch his latte.
>
> The judge pounded his gavel for the courtroom to be silent.
>
> The child screamed for the clown to go away.
>
> The ambulance siren sounded for drivers to clear a path.